# Opening a Visual Studio 2008 sln file creates a Visual Studio folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, svn, projects-and-solutions, solution

this sounds simple but drives me nuts.

I am on Windows 7 and have VS TS 2008 SP1.  When I open a solution file it always creates a 'Visual Studio 2008' folder in the same directory. Then SVN etc wants to add etc. How do I stop this from happening. I tried the registry setting the VisualStudioLocation to %userprofile\docs etc but no joy.

Thanks Mick

Comment: Does this happen for any solution file in different folders?

Comment: Why do you blame Visual Studio instead of SVN?

Comment: because I couldnt see SVN creating a Visual Studio folder Cody. Also I had the problem before I installed SVN but was able to live with it. :-)  Have a solution below though so thanks for looking in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got this sorted from another bit of digging on the internet...

Open the registry... **Run -> Regedit**

Browse the ***Hkey_Current_USER -> Software -> Microsoft -> Visual Studio -> 9.0***

Look at the following keys and set them to

**VisualStudioLocation** = *%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2008*
**VisualStudioProjectsLocation** = *%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects*

This will cause any Visual Studio folders etc to get created there and not in your local solution folder..

Regards Mick

Comment: Thanks add the same problem with visual studio 2012 and win 8, this work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because of your soruce control (SVN). Try changing Tools-->Options-->Source Control